# Django infer a field from other fields

Tags: python, django, class, django-models

I am currently having a model:

```
class Current(models.Model):  
    field1 = models.IntegerField()  
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
    field3 = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to have field3 to be set directly equal to field1 + field2 without actually sending it.
What's the standard way in django to do this?

PS: Yes, I need to save field3 in the database alongwith the other fields.

Comment: What do you mean by "without actually sending it"? Is there a form involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? But not sure why this would need to be saved in the database.

```
class Current(models.Model):  
    field1 = models.IntegerField()  
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
    field3 = models.IntegerField()  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.field3 = self.field1 + self.field2
        super(Current, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the model's save() method. But why do you need to save field3 at all?

Comment: actually field3 is some complex combination of field1 and field2. I need to fetch it frequently. So I would prefer to have that calculated right away.