# getting a django model field from another field

Tags: django-models

i have this model

```
class Person(models.Model):

    picture = models.ImageField(
        default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics', )

    firstName = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    familyName = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    GENDER = [
        ("M", 'Male'),
        ("F", 'Female'),
        ("U", 'UNKNOWN'),

    ]
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=GENDER,
        default="U",
    )
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    remark = models.TextField(default="no remark")
    description_vector = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

i want to infer the description_vector from the picture field (with a method called identifie(pictur) that return a string ) whenever i add a new Person or changing a model image **(if the image didn't change i dont want to change the description_vector)**
i know i can use the save method like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326109/django-infer-a-field-from-other-fields) but i dont know how to specify that when the image change the vector change.

i dont know if it changes anything but i use **django-rest-framowrk** to add and change persons
i know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what your specific doubt is, but I think this might be helpful.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id is not None: # check only when update
        original_picture = self.objects.get(id=self.id).picture

        if original_picture !== self.picture # You must add here your method to evaluate if both images are equal
            self.vector = some_method_to_change_vector(self.picture)

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: yes i think thats what i need i'll try it .... another thing i want to ask if you are familar with this is how to get the image data from the picture ... i mean how to get raw image data as if i read it with open('imagePath', 'rb').read()

Comment: @mahmoudettouahri Not really. I'll advice you to post another question for that.